# my android app it is crashing and i don't know why. I added all the permissions but still crashing.

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

Reciever that start on system boot

public class BootBroadcastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent i = new Intent(context,SmsReceiver.class);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

}

Reciever listening to incoming smses

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private String KEYWORD="GPS";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"))
        {

            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            if (bundle != null)
            {

                //Receiving messages

                try{
                     Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");        
                        SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];   

                        for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) { 
                            smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
                            }

                                      /*Checking for a key word*/
                        if (smsMessage[0].getMessageBody().equalsIgnoreCase(KEYWORD))
                        {
                            Intent  in = new Intent(context, Service.class);
                            context.startService(in);
                        }

                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());

                }
            }

        }

    }

}

package edu.na.aggas.comGpsService;
```

The service that start when a keyword appears in the sms

```
public class Service extends android.app.Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locListener = new mylocationListener();
        locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        disableGps();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        enableGps();

    }

public void enableGps(){

        Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
        intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
        sendBroadcast(intent);  
    }

    public void disableGps(){

        Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
        intent.putExtra("enabled", false);
        sendBroadcast(intent);  
    }
         /*Inner class*/
    class mylocationListener implements LocationListener{

                       /*If the location changes get new coordinates*/
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            if(location != null)
            {
                double plong = location.getLongitude();
                double plat = location.getAltitude();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Longitude: " + plong + "Latitude: " + plat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { 

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,Bundle extras) {

        }

    }

}

Xml

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <service android:name=".Service">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name = "edu.na.aggas.comGpsService.Service">
                </action>
            </intent-filter>      
        </service>

        <receiver android:name=".BootBroadcastReciever">
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name ="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                      <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
              </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
```

Can any one please tell me where problem is and how to solve it.....?

Answer (score 0):

You have to send message to BroadcastReciever so

Use this

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent i = new Intent(context,SmsReceiver.class);
    context.sendBroadcast(i);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If u can add the Log from LogCat, we can help u better.
But for starting, did u add following code in your manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name="BootBroadcastReciever" >

    </receiver>
```

Comment: @Selvin-How can u say that...he will get Force Close if he has not registered the receiver  in his manifest file...plz explain your comment !!

Comment: afaik sentence starting with "did" is the question not the answer ... so its place is in comments and no ... he will not get Force Close for unregisted BroadcastReceiver ... he will not recive broadcast

Comment: @Selvin-It was a suggestion, as I couldn't assume more due to lack of Log !

Answer (score -1):

**Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();**

You cannot show Toast from service, For showing Toast, you need to have activity context. So comment out all Toast Statements and try.

Comment: wrong ... read documentation again : `A toast can be created and displayed from an Activity or Service. If you create a toast notification from a Service, it appears in front of the Activity currently in focus.`

Comment: @Selvin : Read my answer carefully...."For showing Toast, you need to have activity context". In this case he is calling the service from a BroadCastReceiver and thats y I told.